# Get/Set values of dynamical generated input fields using ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an input field which once filled with a number populates that count of additional input fields. I can't figure out how to get the values inserted in those generated input fields. Any help is appreciated, and oh, I did try various things and even with angular.element, or solely with jquery, but failed, so any explanation on how to do this is welcome.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/59/), and the code c/p-ed here:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="cntInputs" placeholder="#Inputs"><br/>

    <input ng-repeat="i in getTimes()" type="text" placeholder="{{i}}" id="input_{{i}}">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="j in getTimes()">
            Inputed value is: {{getValue(j)}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.cntInputs = 0;

    $scope.getTimes=function(){
        var a = new Array();

        for(var i=1; i <= $scope.cntInputs; i++)
            a.push(i);

        return a;       
    };

    $scope.getValue = function(id){
        //here get the value of that inserted in the element with the id of "input_" + id
        return angular.element("input_" + id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So add `ng-model="inputs[i-1]"` to your text field

Then in your controller add `$scope.inputs= [];`

Then in your `getValue` function:  `return $scope.inputs[id-1];`

If you make your getTimes function 0 based you wouldn't need the `-1`s

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/60/

Comment: It a great job , but I have simple modification that instead of using  
ng-model="inputs[i-1]" you can use ng-model="inputs[$index]"